# How to retrieve selected record or its' index in sap.ui.table.Table?

Tags: sapui5, treetable

I have implemented a Tree Table in sapui5 with 'multitoggle' mode. I am trying to get the selected row or its index.
For the index, I have used the function `getSelectedIndex();`
But it returns -1 for the records that have been collapsed under a particular record.

Also, is there any other way to get the selected record (instead of index) from a Tree Table?

Kindly help. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi,
 
You will need to use :`getSelectedIndices()` as you are using MultiToggle selection mode. Method-`getSelectedIndices()` will return array of selected Indexes. Then you can use the method: `oTable.getContextByIndex(index_number).getObject()`: to fetch the selected context object. However, the real problem is that selection of rows are lost once you collapse the group. Waiting for experts to reply on how to retain the selection after collapse.